# running python scripts with matlab

Tags: python

I'm teaching myself a little bit of programming in python and also mathlab. And I need to run a couple of functions I wrote in python with matlab.

I saw this example: 
In python

```
    import sys
    def squared():
        y=x*x
        return y

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = float(sys.argv[1])
        sys.stdout.write(str(squared(x)))
```

then in matlab

```
    [status,result]=system('nameofthescrip', 3)
    status=0
    result=9.0
```

but, I don't know when I try with my functions it doesn't work.

my program goes something like this:

```
    def function_1():
        Shows something on screen
        return

    def function_2():
        hear a sound
        return

    def function_3():
        write a number and press a key
        return

    x=[function_1,funciotion_2,function_3]
    random.shuffle(x)
```

But then I don't know what to put inestead of

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = float(sys.argv[1])
        sys.stdout.write(str(squared(x)))
```

So that I can run it from matlab, just as the example I wrote first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, the code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = float(sys.argv[1])
    sys.stdout.write(str(squared(x)))
```

is run when the script is run, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/2449192). In your case, the code you want to run when the script is run is

```
x=[function_1,function_2,function_3]
random.shuffle(x)
```

so you should put that code inside the if block:

```
if __name__ == '__main':
    x=[function_1,function_2,function_3]
    random.shuffle(x)
```

Then in MATLAB you can invoke the Python in a similar way:

```
[status,result]=system('nameofthescript')
```

There is no input to your script, so you don't need the second argument of the MATLAB `system` function. Make sure you have the correct [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your script!

Comment: ThankS! I understood a lot with your post! Unfortunately I'm having an import-error that I don't know how to fix, I'm working on that right now! But your answer helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `random.shuffle(x)` will just rearrange the list `x`, it won't run or return anything, so your script isn't going to output anything.  If you want to run the functions, you'll have to add something like

```
for f in x:
    f()
```

to the end of your code, and this will loop through the (shuffled) list of functions and then run each one in that (random) order.

If any of your functions include `print`, then you should see the results.  If you don't, you can try replacing any `print` with the `sys.std.write` function you see in the example.

You don't even need the `if __name__=='__main__'` line unless you want to `import` your file but *not* run that part at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm begining to understand how it works.Unfortunately, I'm having an import-error in matlab that I don't seem to be able to fix! However I understood how it worked and could open and run other simpler functions!

Comment: You're welcome @Estefania!  The import error sounds like another problem, so you might be better off asking a separate question.  If my answer helped you please feel free to upvote it or select it with the green checkmark.